# Help me understand why: [self propertyName] works while propertyName doesn't

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So I had a class defined with a property - we'll call it `propertyName` for the sake of this example. I had the property setup with `@synthesize` in my implementation.

I have a method called `objectToNSDictionary` which basically dumps that property into a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [self propertyName], @"propertyName", nil];
```

I return that dict to the caller I use a JSonWriter to convert it to a string and pass it off to some service...

Suffice it to say that the above works. However, my original implementation didn't use `[self propertyName]` but instead just used `propertyName`. When I did that, I always had an error saying `unrecognized selector sent to instance` when I tried to use the object in the caller.

What's the difference in syntax really saying and why does one work and not the other?

Comment: Can you show your other code? I can't see why you would have that error.

Comment: As jtbandes said, please post the code that gives an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error, because that won't normally happen if you just replace the `[self propertyName]` in your code with `propertyName` — and it's hard to tell you what's making the difference if we only have one of the code samples.

Comment: Do you have - in `.h`: `NSString * propertyName;` `@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString * propertyName;` `in.m` `@syncthesize propertyName;`

Answer (score 2):

When you use `[self propertyName]` you are referencing the property you defined for your class, via the synthesized getter method. When you use `propertyName` directly you are bypassing the property and using the class ivar directly. This will work as long as your ivar ***really is*** called *propertyName*, which is not required and might not be the case. Generally its a bad idea to access your ivar directly because doing so circumvents the memory management scaffolding that the compiler generates for you.

You need to post relevant code from your calling class to be able to tell why you are getting a 'selector not recognized' message.

Comment: I kind of suspect something along these lines happened... I had some releases going on which must have released the memory before actually getting the value... ?

Comment: Accessing a released object would have given you a BAD_EXC_ACCESS, not an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'. I'm guessing you've made some changes to your code and can no longer replicate the error?

Comment: @Perception: Accessing freed memory is undefined behavior. It *might* raise `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, or it might work like you expected, or it might give a totally nonsensical result (e.g. you get a different object from the one you expected to be there).

Comment: @Perception: That's not necessarily true. When an object of a different class is allocated at the same address that a different, now deallocated, object held earlier, trying to send the old object (via the address, as always) a message will result in the new object giving you “unrecognized selector sent to instance”.

Comment: @Chuck and Peter - I know that, and should have worded my comment more appropriately but for the sake of brevity. My main point was that you would not get an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' message.

Comment: Well, in theory he could get an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' if another object was allocated and happened to begin precisely on the beginning byte boundary of the released memory. Since the *isa* pointer is the first member of the object struct? This is beyond my current knowledge of Objective C internals, others may wish to chime in.

Comment: @Perception: Your last comment started out right. It doesn't matter where `isa` is in the object structure; all that matters is the new object got allocated at the same address the old object had. Since you still have a pointer to (i.e., the address of) the old object, when you try to send it a message, it goes to the new object; if it's an instance of a different class, then you will get “unrecognized selector sent to instance”. The root cause is the same: You over-released/under-retained the old object.

Comment: @Peter Hosey - I see what you are saying and your right that the only determining factor is that a new object is allocated at the address of the old object. However if memory serves me correct it *is* relevant that the *isa* pointer is the first member of the struct - since references to struct members are actually resolved by offset counters from the beginning of the struct.

Comment: @Perception: That last part is true, but how does that make it important that the `isa` member is first and not, say, third? Why wouldn't this happen if the `isa` lookup looked at `ptr + 24` instead of `ptr + 0`?

Comment: @PeterHosey let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2868/discussion-between-perception-and-peter-hosey)